# How to resize the image of kinect with Processing

Tags: java, image, image-processing, processing, kinect

The output image of using EasyOpenNI with an xbox360 kinect is a small 640 x 480 image, is there anyway to maybe scale it up to fullscreen, or near fullscreen.

I tried using image.resize() but it creates additional images on the top, and the expanded image does not refresh, it gives the initial frame at boot.

Code:

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI kinect;
 
PImage depthCam;
PImage result;

void setup()
{
  size(640, 480);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  background(0);

  kinect  = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  kinect.enableDepth();
 
  result = createImage(width,height,RGB);
}
 
void draw()
{

  background(0);
  kinect.update();

  depthCam = kinect.depthImage();
  int[] depthVals = kinect.depthMap();

  result.loadPixels();
 
  for (int y=0; y<depthCam.height; y=y+5)
  {
    for (int x =0; x<depthCam.width; x=x+5)
    {
      int loc = x+(y*depthCam.width);

      if (depthVals[loc] <= 1200 && depthVals[loc] > 50) { 
        result.pixels[loc] = color(250);
      }
      else if (depthVals[loc] > 1200 && depthVals[loc]< 3000 )
      {
        result.pixels[loc] = color(102);
      }
      else  {
      //otherwise let the pixel value in the result image be white
       result.pixels[loc] = color(0);
      }
 
    }
  }

result.updatePixels();
result.resize(640*2,480*2);
image(result,0,0);

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what appears:
[image]
Everything is working correctly, except for the fact that there are two duplicated streams at the top (that do refresh), and the enlarged stream does not refresh.